# use python requests library to post data to search box

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to figure out, in order to post data to the right form, what is the key, and what is the value. In my opinion, I think the html tag's ID, which has method get, is the key. And the text I put in the text box should be the value.

```
<form id="searchbox_form" class="searchbox_form form man" method="get" action="/submit_search/"     autocomplete="off">
```

So question is, how could I get the webpage html after I putting text in the search box?
Thank you guys, here's my code

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://www.trulia.com/homepage.php?", 
                  data={'searchbox_form form man':'7420 Westlake Ter #1210 20817'})
with open("test.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is submitted using HTTP `GET` method and the submitted url is in the `action` attribute of the form. So you are submitting your query in `http://www.trulia.com/submit_search/`

Now you can approach like this,

```
from urllib import urlencode
import requests
params = {'search': '7420 Westlake Ter #1210 20817'}
search_url = 'http://www.trulia.com/submit_search/?'
url = search_url + urlencode(params)
r = requests.get(url)
# now you get your desired response.
```

You can use firebug or developers tool to see the request.

If it is python 3.x, as tagged, the import should be
`from urllib.parse import urlencode`

Comment: sorry I didn't check my post in the last weekend, your answer works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ? in your URL.
Then change 'searchbox_form form man' to just 'searchbox_form'.

Your requests object will look like:

```
r = requests.post("http://www.trulia.com/homepage.php", data={'searchbox_form': '7420 blahblah'})
```

I think that might work.

The ? mark on the end of the URL is indicating that you're submitting query strings in the URL.
Since you're posting w/form data, the data dictionary(data={}) in your post takes care of adding query strings.

Comment: No it doesn't work... Can you try it on your own machine? I am very appreciated

Comment: Ok.  So I had to open up the Chrome dev tools to see how the request was being sent.

When I hit search, the URL requested was http://www.trulia.com/submit_search/?display=for_sale&search="ZIP_CODE_I_USED_FOR_SEARCH" plus other querystrings that were automatically filled in.

If you search through the page via Inspect Element, you'll see that there's an id="global_nav_searchbox" with an action="/submit_search/".  I think if you change your query to requests.post("http://www.trulia.com/submit_search/", data={"search": "your search argument here"}) then that might work?